# Passing an integer to a formatted string in C

Tags: c, string, integer, formatted-input

I have found information only on conversion from int to string. However, is it possible to pass an *integer* to a formatted string in C?

The code I am trying to execute:

```
char a[] = {
    "%d"
};
a[0]= 0;
printf("%s", a);
```

However, the output is nothing. Have I screwed up in something or should I simply convert the value as the following seems to work:

```
char a[] = {
    "%s"
}
a[0] = "word";
printf("%s", a);
```

Comment: Why not just `printf("%d", 0)`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Besides that the code you are showing is ill-formed. Turn on your warnings, you are assigned a `char*` to a `char` in your second example. This only "works" on accident.

Comment: @Mureinik, firstly I am just curious, secondly I am new to C and am not sure if a loop + printf("%vartype", variable) is the best solution in comparison with what I'm planning to do.

Comment: @pschulz, but the format in the string is "%s", why should it be a char?

Comment: Because you define a char array, which can be *used* as `char*`. But accessing a singular element of the array yields the base type, which is `char`. Your example makes more sense like this (why did you put the initial `"%s"` in `a` any way?): `const char* a = "word"; printf("%s", a);`

Comment: When you write `"somestring"` in your code, that string is stored in the program code (not quite, but like that). This can't be altered, so string literals (that is, when you write strings in `""`) are use as `const char*`. What your first example basically is is: `char a = "word"`, which (now knowing that a string literal is a `const char*`) makes no sense.

Comment: @pschulz put it there because i'm primarily a pythonist and wanted to see if it works in c as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256214/discussion-between-pschulz-and-ani).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. The approach is a bit different.

The most safe method is creating a fixed-size buffer like `char buffer[100]`, then call the function from `stdio.h` called `snprintf`. This allows you to write into buffer any formatted string with any arguments you want.

This is a snippet how to do this in practice:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 100;
    char buffer[size]; // our buffer
    char pattern[] = "%d"; // formatted string; important remark: "%d" matches an integer.
    int num = 24; // the variable which we want to pass

    snprintf(buffer, size, pattern, num); // order of calling this function: a buffer, a size of the buffer, the formatted string, the remaining variables
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! What is the buffer needed for? It's the first time I encounter `sprintf`

Comment: Yes, you are correct @SupportUkraine. I will edit my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Ani `buffer` is needed for storing the resulting string. When you use `printf` the result goes to your terminal i.e. stdout. But when you use `sprintf` the output is saved in a char-array (aka a string). That's what `buffer` is... the variable to hold the result.